# Jquery function return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value

I've created a function to iterate through a UL/LI. This works perfectly, my problem is returning the value to another variable. Is this even possible? What's the best method for this? Thanks!

```
function getMachine(color, qty) {
    $("#getMachine li").each(function() {
        var thisArray = $(this).text().split("~");
        if(thisArray[0] == color&& qty>= parseInt(thisArray[1]) && qty<= parseInt(thisArray[2])) {
            return thisArray[3];
        }
    });

}

var retval = getMachine(color, qty);
```

Comment: It's possible and that's how I would do it. Are you not getting a value returned?

Comment: Your code seems correct, are you able to run Firebug and see if the Console lists anything?

Comment: return won't work this way in $.each. return will just exit the foreach loop.

Comment: This doesn't work because return thisArray[3] only returns from the .each() inner function, it doesn't return from the getMachine function.  As other posters have shown, you need to set thisArray[3] to a local variable and return(false) from the inner function to stop the .each() iteration and then you can return that inner variable from getMachine.

Comment: Return should actually be false or true for an $.each().  Where false is like a break and true is like a continue.

Comment: what if the Your code doesn't go in the if statement? You should handle the other case too. not all control paths returning a value right now. see Milimetric's answer

Comment: For the record, the reason I didn't return false/true initially is because the if statement has only 1 possible match. If it made it to the return, there was no need to continue any further. Thanks again for the all the help everyone!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of the general purpose of the function, but you could always do this:

```
function getMachine(color, qty) {
    var retval;
    $("#getMachine li").each(function() {
        var thisArray = $(this).text().split("~");
        if(thisArray[0] == color&& qty>= parseInt(thisArray[1]) && qty<= parseInt(thisArray[2])) {
            retval = thisArray[3];
            return false;
        }
    });
    return retval;
}

var retval = getMachine(color, qty);
```

Answer (score 19):

The return statement you have is stuck in the inner function, so it won't return from the outer function.  You just need a little more code:

```
function getMachine(color, qty) {
    var returnValue = null;
    $("#getMachine li").each(function() {
        var thisArray = $(this).text().split("~");
        if(thisArray[0] == color&& qty>= parseInt(thisArray[1]) && qty<= parseInt(thisArray[2])) {
            returnValue = thisArray[3];
            return false; // this breaks out of the each
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}

var retval = getMachine(color, qty);
```

Comment: You need to add `return false;` inside of if statement to break from `each()` after the assignment.